# How to show a calculated fields on show.gsp?

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, service, gsp

I'm having some difficulties dealing with calculated non-stored fields. I would liked to show my actual domain classes but their have a lot of fields. So let's consider the following domain class:

```
class ImportantCalculation {
 BigDecimal parameter1
 BigDecimal parameter2
 BigDecimal parameter3
 BigDecimal result1
 BigDecimal result2
 ...
}
```

The result1 and result2 are calculated fields that depend on sub-results of calculations using parameter1, parameter2 and parameter3. Using kind of mathematical notation (actual calculations involve many classes and database queries):

```
subresult1=function(parameter1)
subresult2=function(parameter2,parameter3)
result1=function(subresult1,subresult2)
result2=function(parameter1,subresult2)
```

In the create.gsp this calculations are performed in a Java class which is invoked by a service. This service is used by a controller. And this controller is invoked by a autocomplete jQuery element inside a JavaScript file then displayed in their according fields:

```
Calculations.java -> CalculationsService.groovy -> CalculationsController -> calculations.js -> GSP view.
```

The GSP view contains fields to display sub-results.

It would be easier to store this sub-results but as it can be calculated it's not necessary, but I can't do this with the final results.

So, I need this sub-results to be shown in the show.gsp view and also in the edit.gsp view. But I don't know how to do this. I tried to use Ajax and jQuery but I'm a total newbie on those tools.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Can't you call the same service in the Show and edit gsps ? If it is the same data, you should be able to recalculate those fields, no?

Answer (score 0):

In your gsp's you can use ajax calls to the controller that calculates the results for you and return as JSON. In your gsp, you would have javascript code like:

```
 $.ajax({
        var value = "any value to be passed as param";
        url: "${createLink(controller: 'calculations', action: 'calculate')}",
        data: {key:value}, //in your controller, look for the parameter "key" in params map
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
             //do something with data (the json object rendered by the action 'calculate')   
            }
        }

    });
```

And in your controller, you would have an action calculating the result or getting the result already stored somewhere, like:

```
def calculate() {
    def result = calculatorService.doSomething()
    render result as JSON
}
```

The line with "render" command is the one sending the result back to the caller (your javascript 'success' function).

You can see examples of the same thing [here](http://www.kromhouts.net/blog/grails/updating-multiple-page-elements-with-grails-and-ajax/) and [here](http://moongrails.blogspot.com.br/2008/12/grails-ajax-powered-validation.html).